# Lumen database connection character encoding

Tags: php, lumen

I have a problem with Lumen connection character encoding

I tried everything and I figured that the connection is the problem

In a lumen model, I created a new mysqli connection like this

```
$sql = "SELECT summary FROM exp_fb_assessments WHERE aid=8192";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["summary"] . "<br>";
}
```

And right after that, I do this to see the output of the default `DB` Lumen connection

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT summary FROM exp_fb_assessments WHERE aid=8192");
echo $results[0]->summary;
```

As you can see both are exactly the same but I get different results

```
Test 例如：发表 这篇论文 什么时候 是 的 
这篇论文是什么时候发表的？ 
Test ä¾‹å¦‚ï¼šå‘è¡¨ è¿™ç¯‡è®ºæ–‡ ä»€ä¹ˆæ—¶å€™ æ˜¯ çš„ 
è¿™ç¯‡è®ºæ–‡æ˜¯ä»€ä¹ˆæ—¶å€™å‘è¡¨çš„ï¼Ÿ
```

How can I fix this or at least debug and find where the problem with the connection is.

NOTE: I tried setting these in my `.env` file:

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8
DB_CHARACTERSET=ut8
DB_COLLATION=utf8_unicode_ci
```

still not working.

Comment: it seems issue in  database and table charset .Please change db and table collation
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER table exp_fb_assessments modify column summary varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;